# SQL: Linking Column Value to Column Name to fulfill some conditions

Tags: mysql, sql-server

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YboIc.png)

Base on the image, the TABLE B is my main table while the TABLE A is the rules or conditions for the TABLE B.

I want to write a query such that when rules 1 in Table A, which stands for column [C1] having indicator 3.
Then find the respective column name in TABLE B with respective value and replace the FILL value. The result that I wanted is like TABLE C.

How can I do so?

Comment: I don't get it - why do only rows 2 and 3 get an updated fill?

Comment: coz row 2 have 3 in c1 and 6 in c2 that fulfill the indicator in Table A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to join based on an `OR` condition over both columns

Preferably aggregate with `MAX` just in case there are multiple matches

```sql
SELECT
  b.c1,
  b.c2,
  ISNULL(a.fill, b.fill) AS fill
FROM TableB b
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MAX(fill) AS fill
    FROM TableA a
    WHERE a.[column] = 'c1' AND b.c1 = a.ind
       OR a.[column] = 'c2' AND b.c2 = a.ind
) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `pivot`. Changing column names in table A from rows into columns.

```
select B.c1,B.c2, (CASE WHEN A.ind IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS fill
from tblB AS B
left outer join
(select *
from 
(
  select [column], ind, fill
  from tblA 
) src
pivot
(
  max(fill)
  for [column] in ([c1], [c2])
) piv
) AS A
ON (B.c1 = A.ind or B.c2 = A.ind)
```